# Stack pointer difference for char pointer and array

Tags: c

I have a `char` array as below:

```
 char buffer[100]
```

And another `char` pointer as below:

```
 char *buffer
 buffer = malloc(100)
```

When I use [GDB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Debugger) to check out the stack pointer, they are actually different. Why?

Comment: I see at least two different ways in which `char buffer[100]` can be instantiated. Is `char buffer[100]` within the block of `char *buffer` or is it global? Are you asking the question why `char buffer[100]` appears on the stack and `buffer = malloc(100)` does not? `malloc` does not get its memory from the stack.

Comment: There's no such thing as a stack or a heap in C. It's a common implementation, but it's not required by the standard.

Comment: This question is going to keep coming up. We should keep this question open and close the others as dups, because this has an excellent answer (pretty pictures).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That is because the `char buffer[100]` will be allocated on the stack, which will occupy 100 bytes of storage. Therefore the stack pointer `esp`/`rsp` will point to a lower memory (taking stack grows downwards)

```
 +-    +------------+   <-- ebp
 |     |            |
 b     +------------+
 u     |            |
 f     +------------+
 f     |            |       holds 100 elements of buffer array       
 e     +------------+
 r          .
            .
 a          .
 r     +------------+
 r     |            |
 +-    +------------+  <-- esp
```

And in the case of `char *buffer` only one `char *` type object's memory (`sizeof (char *)`) will be allocated on the stack. When you do `buffer = malloc (100)` the base address of a memory block with 100 bytes guaranteed will be returned. This allocated memory is generally taken from the heap. Therefore now `buffer` holds the base address of the just allocated memory block. So, in this case because the memory is from the heap, and the stack only holds the `char *` type object, therefore the stack pointer is on higher location (taking stack grown downwards)

```
    +------------+   <-- ebp
    |   0xabcd   |             buffer , char * type
    +-----+------+   <-- esp
          | 
          |
          |             0xabcd 0xabce
          |             +-----+-----+-----+       +-----+-----+
          +------------>|     |     |     | . . . |     |     | 
                        +-----+-----+-----+       +-----+-----+
                                     0xabcf . . .

                        |                                     |
                        +------ 100 bytes mem block in heap --+
```

Also note  Richard J. Ross III's comment.