# C pointers and arrays/ 'sizeof' operator

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, sizeof

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Stack pointer difference for char pointer and array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12760229)

To illustrate my question:

```
int main(void){
    int myary[20];
    int *myaryPtr;
    myaryPtr = myary;

    sizeof(myary); // Will it return 80? Correct?
    sizeof(myaryPtr); // Will it return 4? Correct?
    return 0;
}
```

First off, is my assumption correct?

And then assuming my assumption is correct, what is the detailed explanation? I understand that my 20 element array is 80 bytes, but isn't the name `myary` merely a pointer to the first element of  the array? So shouldn't it also be 4?

Comment: Subject to `sizeof(int) == 4`  and `sizeof(int *) == 4`, the first of which is usually the case and the second is right for 32-bit systems (`sizeof(int *) == 8` on 64-bit systems), your assumptions about `sizeof` are correct.  Arrays are not identical to pointers — witness the different result from `sizeof`.  But this must be a duplicate of a number of other questions...the difficulty is finding them.

Comment: Sorry, I had difficult finding one that matched my exact question.

Comment: You might like to read section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://c-faq.com/).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, your assumption is correct, assuming an `int` and a pointer are both 4 bytes long on your machine.

And no, arrays aren't pointers.  The array name sometimes decays into a pointer in certain contexts, but they aren't the same thing.  There is a [whole section of the comp.lang.c FAQ](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html) dedicated to this common point of confusion.

Comment: simplest example is that array `char string[] = "test"` takes 5 bytes, while pointer to array `char *string = "test"` takes 5 bytes for string and `sizeof(char *)` for pointer itself.

Comment: Ok, so an array is an object in the function it is local to, and then the array decays to a pointer when passed to other functions?

Comment: When is the array name *not* considered to be a pointer?

Comment: @Eric, yes, a function call is one place the array name decays to a pointer.  The FAQ has a lot of details.

Comment: @Aposperite, all the details you could possibly want are in the FAQ I linked in my answer.

Comment: @Vlad: Yes, basically. More specifically, a function is not allowed to have a parameter of array type in C -- if you try to write one it will be interpreted as a pointer type instead. So, "array decays to a pointer when passed to other functions" *because* it sees that that function takes a pointer parameter.

Comment: @Aposperite: to name a few, the `&` operator on an array results in a pointer to an array. Also, `sizeof`.

Answer (score 3):

The size of the array is not stored in memory in either case, whether you declare it as `int myArr[20]` or `int* myArrPtr`.

What happens is that `sizeof()` is replaced (by the compiler) with a **constant value**.

Therefore, because `myArr` was specified with a fixed size prior to compilation, the compiler knows just how big the amount of memory allocated is. With `myArrPtr`, you could dynamically allocate different array sizes, so only the size of the *type* is stored.

Comment: `sizeof` isn't always constant - it works for VLAs, for example.

Comment: In that case the compiler could replace a `sizeof(int vla[n])` with an `n * sizeof(int)` where `sizeof(int)` would be a constant. Also section 6.15 of the above mentioned [FAQ](http://c-faq.com/)

Comment: That's exactly what it does do. I was just commenting for clarity, since your answer says it's replaced with a constant, and that's not always the case.

Comment: Very true. However, I haven't had experience with VLAs as the last time I tried to use them, I got compiler errors/warnings, so I've stuck with malloc/free