# C++ Constructor from char* to int[]/int*

Tags: c++, casting, char

I have a constructor with parameter `char*` (only numbers) and I would like make a simple mathematical operations. I thought to add new parameter to constructor `int[]`/`int*` to make it easier.

header:

```
class BigNum {
    char *value;
    int* arr;

    public:
        BigNum(char*, int * = 0) {};
        BigNum();
};
```

cpp:

```
BigNum::BigNum(char* value, int *tab){
    int length = sizeof(value) / sizeof(char*);
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        arr[i] = value[i];
    }
}
```

Can I do something like this? It does not even compile.
What I could to do to on this sample change `char*` to `int`.

Comment: Why not for length look till the null charecter and you have some undefined behavior if tab is not the same length as value

Comment: Int* what is supposed to be?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please read the help section before posting a question. While your question isn't a terrible first question, I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish. Could you please add that to the beginning of the question with an example maybe?

Comment: `int length = sizeof(value) / sizeof(char*);` this won't calculate the size of your array. It's a constant value 1. What you were aiming for `int length = sizeof(value) / sizeof(char);` won't calculate the size either. It's also a constant value unfortunately. See:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14298710/c-pointers-and-arrays-sizeof-operator

Answer (score 1):

> its not even compile

It doesn't compile because you have defined `BigNum(char*, int *)` twice. Once in the header, and then in the source file.

Solution: Only define the constructor once. Extra hint: When a program doesn't compile, the compiler will tell you why in the diagnostic message.

---

This doesn't do what you think it does:

> ```
> int length = sizeof(value) / sizeof(char*);
> ```

`length` will always be 1, because the type of `value` is `char*`. I suspect that your intention is that `value` points to an array and you want to calculate the length of that array. Well, calculating the length of an array from a pointer to an element of that array is not possible.

Solution: You have to a) pass the length of the array as an argument or b) specify that the array must be a terminated string, in which case you can calculate the length by iterating the string until the termination character is found.

---

You access `arr[i]` without initializing `arr`:

> ```
> arr[i] = value[i];
> ```

The behaviour is undefined.

Solution: You have to allocate an array.

---

> what i could to do to on this sample change char* to int.

It depends on how you want to change it. If you want to convert a pointed character digit to `int`, you can use the fact that digits are required to be sequential in all native character encodings (that are supported by C++). From that fact, we know that subtracting the value of digit character from the value of `0` character, we get the numeric value that the digit character represents:

```
char* c = address_of_some_digit;
int value_of_digit = '0' - *c;
```