# for sizeof(x) VS while ([x] != '\0') in C

Tags: c, pointers, char, sizeof, c-strings

I'm just wondering if there was a difference between using

```c
for(i = 0; i < sizeof(argv[1]) / sizeof(argv[1][0]); i++) {
```

and

```c
while (argv[1][i] != '\0')
```

I'm just curious and I can't find anything about it.

(The objective is to `putchar` every character of the `char*`)

Comment: `sizeof(argv[1])` is the size of the pointer. `argc` tells you the length of the array `*argv[]`.

Comment: @WeatherVane Looks like the OP is looking to find the length of a single parameter, not number of them

Comment: To get the length of `argv[1]` please use `strlen(argv[1])`

Comment: You need to understand the difference between pointers and arrays. If you get `argv` from `main()` it is a pointer to (array of) pointer(s) to (array of) `char`. `argv[1]` is a pointer and `sizeof argv[1]` will return the size of the pointer, not the array.

Comment: `while (argv[1][i] != '\0')` is the same as `while (argv[1][i])`

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14298710/c-pointers-and-arrays-sizeof-operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an essential difference in the two conditions.

The expression `argv[1]` is a pointer having the type `char *` and usually occupies either 4 or 8 bytes depending on the used system that is equal to the value of the expression `sizeof(argv[1]) / sizeof(argv[1][0])` or equivalently of the expression `sizeof( argv[1] )` because `sizeof( argv[1][0] )` is the same as `sizeof( char )` and the last is always equal to `1`

On the other hand the pointer can point to a string with much more (or less) characters than 4 or 8.

But even if you will apply the `sizeof` operator for a character array (instead of a pointer) declared for example like

```
char s[] = "Hello";
```

then even in this case the conditions of the loops will be different. That is this for loop

```
for(i = 0; i < sizeof( s ) / sizeof( s[0]); i++) {
```

is equivalent to

```
for(i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
```

because the terminating zero is also included in the array. That is the body of the loop will get the control also for the character `'\0'`.

While this loop

```
while ( s[i] != '\0')
```

stops its iterations when the character `'\0'` is encountered.

Here is a demonstrative program that shows the difference. The program outputs ASCII codes of symbols.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char s[] = "Hello";
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < sizeof( s ) / sizeof( s[0]); i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d ", s[i] );
    }
    
    putchar( '\n' );
    
    size_t i = 0;
    
    while ( s[i] != '\0' )
    {
        printf( "%d ", s[i] );
        ++i;
    }
    
    putchar( '\n' );
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
72 101 108 108 111 0 
72 101 108 108 111
```

Answer (score -2):

They are not the same thing (although they're close).

The first one

```c
for(i = 0; i < sizeof(argv[1]) / sizeof(argv[1][0]); i++) {
```

means:

1. Set `i` to `0`
2. `sizeof(argv[1]) / sizeof(argv[1][0])` means `strlen(argv[1])`, so it means

```
while i is less than the length of argv[1]
```

which is basically the same thing as

```c
int i = 0;
while(argv[1][i++] != '\0')
```

There are 2 differences:

1. In the second one, `i` is never set to `0`
2. In the second one, `i` is never incremented (although in the loop itself it may be incremented)

Comment: `sizeof(argv[1]) / sizeof(argv[1][0])` does not mean `strlen(argv[1])`. The former is the size of the pointer `argv[1]` divided by the size of the `char` `argv[1][0]`, and this will generally not be the same as the length of the string that starts at `argv[1]`, as the size of the pointer has no relation to whatever string was passed to the program.